# JRuby on rails: which gem is supported by juby to render complex json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rabl

I am running jruby application with rails platform.  In my previous ruby on rails application I was using rabl gem to render json response.

Since my current technology stack is jruby on rails hence i am not sure whether jruby support rabl gem or not. I have checked rabl gem documentation and didn't found any reference that says it supports jruby.

I want to know whether rabl gem support jruby and if not then how to send complex json response in rails.

Answer (score 0):

it's pure .rb and does not have any C-exotic dependencies thus it should work.
if you search the issue tracker for JRuby you'll find: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/544 ... which seems to not block the gem working under JRuby.